# What is the difference between WordPress Business plan vs self hosted WordPress (WordPress developer perspective)?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, wordpress.org

**Short version of question** :  : I am not asking the difference between WordPress.com vs WordPress.org.... I am asking difference between WordPress.com Business plan vs WordPress.org

**Long version of question** :

> According to https://wordpress.com/pricing/, **WordPress business plan
>   allow to install third-party themes and plugins**.

So what is the difference between WordPress Business plan vs self hosted WordPress?

In other word, what are the limitation (WordPress developer perspective) of WordPress Business plan when comparing self hosted WordPress?

Comment: this do not even remotely related to wordpress development

Comment: @MarkKaplun why not? Seems like WordPress business plan is a hosted version of WordPress.org which allow to install third-party themes and plugins too.. Then we can use wordpress.com business plan to develop wordpress sites... I mean they allow custom plugins and themes... Then we don't wont to worry about third party hosting because Wordpress handles them.

Comment: development === writing code. selecting hosting !== writing code

Comment: @MarkKaplun That's true... But development all related to hosting environment too. So basically if WordPress it self  handle them, developers wan't need to worry about hosting environment issues when developing and moving sites...............

Comment: developmetn is also related to drinking good coffee in the morning and eating nice pizza in the evening, but still cooking questions are off topic here

Comment: @MarkKaplun Yes, According to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, cooking questions are off topic... It is 100% clear.... But server configuration for WordPress  are on topic according to that article..... So if WordPress it self handle hosting means developers don't want to worry about server configuration...................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First it is important to note the difference between *Business Plan* and regular WordPress *com*. To my knowledge *Business Plan* accounts are *not* hosted on regular dot com grid, but are based on infrastructure of more conventional managed hosting company they've acquired (not sure if completely) while back.

So the closest analogue for it would be a *managed* hosts that specialize in hosting WordPress, being *more managed* on a scale and offering some cross-integration with dot com functionality.

Their support materials cover [nuances of Business Plan in detail](https://en.support.wordpress.com/business-plan/).

In a nutshell difference with *less managed* self–hosted site seem to be:

- no direct filesystem access (no arbitrary file edits);
- black list of some plugins that are not allowed;
- additional features related to dot com offers;
- ability to migrate to/from regular dot com grid.

Overall I would call it *highly managed* WP hosting solutions, which is aimed more at site owners than developers.